# Parse CSV to Extract Filenames and Rename Files (Python)

Tags: pandas, csv

I'm looking to try and extract filenames from a comma CSV, rename the files they refer to by sequential numbering, then going back to the CSV in the process.

I am able to extract all the first column:

```
import pandas as pd
my_data = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=',', header=0, usecols=[0])
```

And then the list of entries that I need:

`values = list(x for x in my_data["full path"])`

From there I want to use that path to rename each file sequentially as per its path(1.msg, 2.msg, 3.msg), then go back and update the CSV with the "new" path.

My CSV looks like:

```
full path, name, data1, data2

\path\to\a\file.msg,data,moredata,evenmoredata
```

Existing file path:

`\path\to\a\file.msg`

New file path:

`\path\to\a\1.msg`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is your goal to rename the file on the disk, or to rename its path just into the CSV content?

Comment: Both, the CSV is used as a reference to import the files. The files need to be numbered sequentially as their filename, maintaining the metadata within the CSV as well. So basically I want to use the CSV to create a new CSV, then use the old and new CSVs to rename the files.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly modify the `dataframe` and the file by iterating trough the dataframe itself. Once you have edited the desired rows, you persist the dataframe by rewriting it to a csv file (the same if you want to overwrite it). I assume here that `file_path` is the name of the column containing the filepath: change it accordingly.

Explanations come with the code comments

```
import os
import pandas as pd

# I'm assuming everything is correct up to the data reading
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=',', header=0, usecols=[0])

# You can iterate trough the index of the dataframe itself. Were it inconsistent, you can use a custom one (here `k`)
k = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   # Extract the current file path, `/path/to/file.msg
   fp = row['file_path']

   # Extract the filename, e.g. `file.msg`
   fn = os.path.basename(fp)

   # Extract the dir path, e.g. `/path/to
   dir_path = os.path.dirname(fp)

   # split and separate from the extention
   name, ext = os.path.splitext(fn)


   # Reconstruct the new filepath
   new_path = os.path.join(dir_path, str(k) + ext)

   # Important to try in order to avoid any prohibited access to the file or its absence 
   try:
      os.rename(fp,new_path)
   except:
      # Here you can enrich the code to handle different specific exceptions
      print(f'Error: file {fp} cannot be renamed')
   else:
      # If the file was correctly replaced, you can modify the dataframe. Put this code outside the try-except-else block to modify the dataframe in any case. NOTE: the index here MUST be that of the dataframe! Not your custom one.

      df.at[index, 'file_path'] = new_path
      
      k = k + 1

# Overwrite the dataframe. Adjust accordingly!
df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

Disclaimer: I couldn't try the code above. In case of any slip, I'll correct it as soon as possible